# TypeScript 'using'

Tags: typescript

In C# one can use a using clause at the top of your file, which enables the use of types within that namespace without explicitly having to specify the full namespace to reference those types.
Does TypeScript provide an alternative for that?

Comment: I see... the thing that comes close is using a shorter alias. I'd say that's far less ideal than simply a 'using' statement. The namingcollisions (in my projects) are rare, and if you run into those exceptional cases, you can simply specify the full namespace to avoid the problem. A namespace alias could be of help if it gets a bit bloated.  So, I'll submit a feature request!

Comment: @SteveFenton, that question is about aliasing types and namespaces, whereas this one is about including a namespace in the current context.

Comment: Yes sam ... you're correct. The more time i spend in typescript, the more i whish that feature were available... unfortunately the issue on codeplex was not accepted and closed. Not alligned with ecma specs.

Comment: Use `import` for exported modules

Answer (score 13):

In TypeScript the closest you can come to being able to directly use external modules is aliasing. As shown in the [TypeScript Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-alias), it is used like this:

```
module Shapes {
    export module Polygons {
        export class Triangle { }
        export class Square { }
    }
}

import polygons = Shapes.Polygons;
var sq = new polygons.Square(); // Same as 'new Shapes.Polygons.Square()'
```

This doesn't put the interfaces on the root scope of the module because this could introduce naming conflicts if the Polygons module was updated and makes it clear that you are referencing something external.